# How to give a sequece of reshaped numpy array as input to CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've tried "You can add CNN model first(with input shape=(30,90,1622)), and use LTSM model to encapsulate CNN model."

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.05)
x_train.shape ---->(85, 30, 1662)


model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(3, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape= 
(30,90,1622))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))
```

but am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, 
found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1662)
```

Comment: what about your train_data shape ?

Comment: model required minimum 4 dimension array !

Answer (score 0):

The **input to a Conv2D layer** should be having shape as :
`(samples, channels, width, height)` and the output from your Embedding is 3D, not 4D as it should be. You should define how to interpret the Embedding output as an image, maybe you should add a channels dimension and set it to 1.

Your input shape is currently :

> x_train.shape ---->(85, 30, 1662)

With the available set of dimensions, use this code for converting it to 4d.

```
import numpy as array

input = array.reshape(input_data, (-1,85, 30, 1662))
```

example :

Also, TimeDistributed requires an initialization of a tf.keras.Layer.layer instance.

> ```
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(3, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape= 
> (30,90,1622))))
> ```

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed#raises), it is a reason for raising the ValueError.

[image]

**Fix :**

```
 TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(convnet)(input_shape)
```